# Compiling multiple Typescript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-construction, webserver, typescript

My nodejs Typescript server has grown in complexity and now relies on a few classes defined in another .ts file. This has created a strange compilation problem:

- `tsc server.ts` compiles everything fine. But `node server.js` crashes at
  the first line that instantiates a class from the other .ts file
- `tsc --out server.js server.ts` results in the error message: "module
  emit collides with emitted script"
- `tsc --out serv.js server.ts` seems to work but actually compiles
  everything EXCEPT server.ts. The code from the other files is there and `node serv.js` just returns without any output

I'm not the only one with this error, https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/294 unfortunately the solution on codeplex doesn't work for me.

How do I use `tsc` correctly ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `server.ts` dependencies need to be modules that export their surface area with top-level `export` directives, and `server.ts` should load them using `import` directives. The root cause here is that TypeScript has two different sorts of universes for compilation.

The first is the default one that you'd use for regular webpages, where some simple loader takes 1 or more source files in some fixed order and executes them in that order, and you're on your own for dependency ordering. This is called "*program*" compilation. In program compilation, you might do side-by-side compilation (a.ts => a.js, b.ts => b.js), or you might do concatenated compilation using `--out` ((a.ts + b.ts) => out.js).

In *program* compilation, you refer to your references using `///<reference>` tags. If those references are to source files (`.ts`), they'll get concatenated in to the output if using `--out`, or emitted as a side-by-side `.js` file otherwise. If those references are to a declaration file (`.d.ts`), you're basically saying you will be getting definitions for those files loaded via the external loader (i.e. a `<script>` tag in the browser).

The second is the kind of compilation you'd use for node.js or other environments that do asynchronous or idempotent module loading with runtime dependency resolution. This called "*module*" compilation. Here, the `--module` flag you pass to `tsc` matters, and the only valid thing to do is side-by-side compilation, because loading a single file as a module is (generally) how the module loaders in node.js, etc work.

In *module* compilation, you use the `export` keyword on a top-level object (function, class, module, interface, or var) to control what's available to code that refers to you using `import`. You should only ever have `/// <reference>` tags that point to `.d.ts` declaration files, because the module-based runtime loaders don't have a notion of loading a naked JS file. You won't compile with `--out`.

You **never** want to mix and match these compilation modes, because it simply is not going to work. In fact, in 0.8.2.0, `tsc` will simply issue an error if you try to do this.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. At last I understood when to use modules and when to use reference paths

Comment: Would you perhaps have any way to provide some example using your answer? I'm trying to have multiple files using Phaser.io+TypeScript, but when I'm running my app, in the second file i have a class extending Namespace.Class, but I get an error saying that Namespace was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I have a web app with a lot of TypeScript files. Here is how I solved this problem:

1. Created a global _references.ts file in the ~/Scripts dir. This file has a *reference path=...* for each ts file in the web project.
2. Next I generated this file using a T4 template because its was becoming a pain to manage by hand.
3. Also, using the T4 template, I ordered the references in *_references.ts* according to my TypeScript dependencies. e.g. All ..Base.ts files at the top.
4. Also, I created a tsc argument file which starts with -out app.js followed by a list of every ts file in the project.  This was also generated using T4 and I called it *app.tsproj*.
5. Finally, I call *tsc @app.tsproj* to generate the JavaScript with all dependencies correctly ordered.

_references.ts T4 template: https://gist.github.com/danabenson/5224712

app.tsproj T4 template: https://gist.github.com/danabenson/5224718